# Angular2 typeahed search with Promise

Tags: angular, promise, semantic-ui, typeahead, angular2-forms

I'm using Angular2 and Semantic-UI for creating a search element in my form that make a "typeahead" search.

Here is the code in the Component that calls the service:

```
getData(typeahead: string): void {
    this.myDataService.getData(typeahead).then(list => {
        this.list = list;
    });
}
```

And here is the code in the template for the search element:

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="ui search">
        <div class="ui icon input">
            <input class="prompt" type="text" [formControl]="myForm.controls.item">
            <i class="search icon"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="results"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I made some tries according to the [examples](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html#/examples) provided by Semantic-UI.
But i cannot make it work.

```
$('.ui.search')
  .search({
    apiSettings: {
      url: '//api.github.com/search/repositories?q={query}'
    },
    fields: {
      results : 'items',
      title   : 'name',
      url     : 'html_url'
    },
    minCharacters : 3
  })
;
```

It should invoke the service every time the user type new input, but i cannot figure out how to deal with it.
Do you have any idea on how to use Angular2 Promise with jQuery code of the Semantic-UI search element?

Comment: If you create a plunkr, we'll be able to help. Also, what error are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any error, i can't figure out how to use my async call with `apiSettings` that seems to get an url, not a promise.

Comment: Can you place this in a `plunkr`. I'll help you fix it if you can place it there.

Comment: I will came back on this next week... can you wait? ':D

Comment: sure. just tag me

Comment: A promise only resolves once, this is a classic use case for an RxJS observable

Comment: @inspired Here is the Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/9VeyJ8VDwDM4bT647O2N . Sorry if i'm so late.